# Get id from metabox dropdown

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, front-end

Im using [Reusable Metaboxes](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes) (old but still works) and I created a metabox that allows the user to pick a post from a list of custom post types. Right now that works pretty well, I can see all the posts in a list and I pick one and save.

The data I see when I call the_meta() shows me that the field is indeed saving the id of the post I called:

episode_guestid: a:1:{i:0;s:2:"18";}

But I don't know how to get the id (in this case 18 - and this needs to be dynamic depending on the chosen post) and use it to display things from that post: title, featured image, metaboxes content.

Tried the "easiest one" with no success (so I will need help with figuring out how to display the metabox data from that post as well):

```
$guestid = $post_meta_data['episode_guestid'][0]; ?>
<h1> Featuring: <?php echo unserialize($guestid);  ?> </h1>
```

Hope someone can help me out with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_meta` is a very bare-bones method. The return value you're seeing is raw, unserialized data. WordPress uses PHP serialization to store complex values like `Array`s and `Object`s as a `string` value. Have a look at [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

```php
$guest_id   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'episode_guestid', true );
$guest_post = get_post( $guest_id[0] );
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $guest_post );
```

You should see the post you're looking for. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: yes, I see all the details of the post I chose :D thanks! now... if you have the time to point me into the right direction to actually get info from the post like title or a metabox that would be amazing.

Comment: I see echo get_the_title($guest_post);  works! :D I will try to do more tests with other info and accept this answer

Comment: Thanks! You can use methods like `get_the_title`, which you've found, and `get_the_content`, `get_the_post_thumbnail`, etc.